# What is [Foo.Bar.Baz] called?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

The below is a line of code from an FTP automation script.

```
$FTPRequest = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create("$RemoteFile")
```

My question is, what is `[System.Net.FtpWebRequest]`? I mean what is it called? Is it a class or a .net object or what else? How can I get help on such things or find out/list out if other such objects exist? Like `Get-Help` or `Get-Command`, so that I can explore or unlock the limitations with default PowerShell commands.

Comment: It's a class in the .NET framework, throwing it in Google would have given you this as a first result: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx. Use of .NET classes in PowerShell leans towards programming rather than simple scripting.

Comment: [See also](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25333.discover-the-dot-net-namespace-and-wmi-class-powershell.aspx).

Comment: It's called a *type* - and the syntax you show exposes the *static members* of said type (methods, properties etc.)